# RTF Copy for Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, netbeans, documentation, copy-paste, rtf

Is there a way to Copy my Code form Netbeans 7.3 formated and colored into my Word document?
I tried NP++ but this isnt the Same color code as in my base IDE, and searched some Plugins but there was no for Netbeans 7.3.

I tried this one here [formatted-text-copy](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/43281/formatted-text-copy), but there was a error while tried to install it.
[Picture](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8hL4DlOr9q_RTlwcnd5bG40cmM/edit?usp=sharing)

Is there a way to fix this or to go a different way?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can edit styles for all of the languages in `Settings -> Style Configurator...`, select `Java` and change the colors for your need. You can view the current colors in Netbeans in `Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors`, select `Java` and you will see the colors for each elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try: [Netbeans RTF Copy plugin](http://semisignal.com/?p=2905).

You need to manually install it, and its not perfect (variables highlight as green in the IDE aren't green in the RTF copy for example) - but it does a reasonable job and is fine for simple use cases - such as copying highlighted text into emails/blogs simply and quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Special copy/paste - plugin detail](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=9275) plugin.

1. Download the latest version for Netbeans 6.8 (i.e. **1246304508433_org-netbeans-modules-specialcopypaste.nbm**).
2. Install this NBM file using the **Downloaded** tab of **Tools -> Plugins**. It will prompt you to install **Express Language Lexer** plugin as well. Say yes to install both.

I tried this plugin with Netbeans 6.9.1 as well as 7.3 and it works fine: color preserved, font is fixed width (although the bold font is not preserved, but I am very happy already).

Answer (score 0):

It is required to install a plug-in  access it form here:

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/54459/rtf-copy-paste-for-netbeans-8-0

to install it, you need first insatall "org.netbeans.libs.junit4"